# How to reboot via cron on scheduled basis. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a very simple script that works from the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
reboot
```

When I put a call to execute the script into root users crontab -e using the following format it does not run. It does run the first two commands, just that last one is giving me grief. I have no MTA installed as I do not need it.

```
*/10 * * * * service jwtpay restart
0 3 * * * bash /root/backup/mongo.backup.s3.sh kickass /root/backup >/dev/null 2>&1
0 */3 * * * bash /root/reboot.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried sending the script output to a log file rather than /dev/null, and reviewing the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the script is not executable... Since you use root's crontab why call the binary via a script and not the binary itself? Use the full path to the binary. It may vary on your system. Find out where it is with `which reboot`.

```
0 */3 * * * /sbin/reboot
```

Don't forget to restart the `cron` daemon, after changeing the crontab.

Comment: I did make the sript executable. However, This suggestion works. I went the /sbin/shutdown -r now route as well with the same results.